# Rails syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a very simple **Rails** program and have a problem. I try to make a `home.html.erb` file, and here is my code

[image: Rails syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end]

I am very sorry I can not upload the code because it was too long.

My problem is, when I tried to open the page

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

it said that I had the problem

> app/views/pages/home.html.erb:24: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end

But I think that I have enough `</div>`, so I still do not know why I have that problem?

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: You forgot `%` - it should be `<% end %>` instead of `<%end>`.

Comment: BTW this is Ruby syntax error, so it comes from erb parser, which, frankly, doesn't care about your code's HTML compatibility at all, so it won't complain for things like missing `</div>` etc.

Comment: There is a syntax typo <% end %> instead of <% end >

Comment: paste your home.html.erb, you will get the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in closing `<% end %>` tag in you erb file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax typo `<% end %>` instead of `<% end >`